# Why does Kotlin in Android Studio freeze when trying to access non existent array element?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin, array-indexing

I've come across interesting behavior of Kotlin in Android Studio. When I try to log an element of an array dynamically where the index supplied is -1 and the array is empty, the program freezes in the emulator but never throws an error.

Example code:

```
val myObjects = mutableListOf<MyObject>()
val objIndex = -1
...
Log.d(TAG, "Non-existent element: ${myObjects[objIndex].myValue}") //stuck here, doesn't move past
```

What causes this seemingly infinite loop or pause in the Kotlin code execution?

Comment: Wasn't able to reproduce. Post Kotlin version and which emulator and SDK you use.

Comment: It throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in my case. Program shouldn't go into infinite loop, can't reproduce. Can you try to use the debugger and determine if that's the line where program gets stuck?

Comment: Sure, I was using SDK version 29 and Kotlin 1.4.0. I know it stopped there because I was logging various steps from multiple parts of the loop and the output just froze. Maybe it was an emulator issue. I didn't dive too much into it and moved my code past the point where it would happen, but I remember the list was empty when the program froze. I guess it wasn't a Kotlin issue.